# Dimming multiple led light bulbs (parallel or in series)

Tags: led

I'd like to install 5 [dimmable led bulbs.](https://www.electrocirkel.com/nl/retail/product/ledrustieke27st64-6w-goud2100-longfilament-dim)

I'm trying to find how to connect them. But I can't get a clear answer. I can get information of the benefits of wiring leds in series/parallel but none of them mention a dimmer.

The question is if I should wire them in series or in parallel? 
And does this affect what kind of dimmer I need?

Answer (score 5):

Those are light bulbs.

You **must** connect them in parallel just like you would connect other 240V light bulbs in parallel.

You **must** use a dimmer intended for LED lights.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are referring to light bulbs which will be fitted to the mains they need to be in parallel.**

Also, if one of the LEDs were to go, in parallel the rest would still operate hence why most mains equipment are fitted that way.

I hope that helps.

Comment: The OP is referring to LED light bulbs, not LEDs (the individual components).

Comment: Ah ok. Then they have to be parallel. He /she didn't specify so I was unsure. 

Comment: Ok edited. I didn't see that link either. - sorry

Answer (score 0):

Mains power is a **constant-voltage** system.   As such, everything is wired in parallel.

Constant-current power is not unheard-of in mains wiring, *however it is notoriously dangerous* and as such, is used in extreme specialty applications and *requires special handling* - e.g. shorting the output of CC transformers to keep them from trying to create infinite voltage.  Transformers don't have crowbar/limiting circuits like electronic supplies do.

Series would be a *really weird* thing to do, and you would need precautions against a device malfunctioning, or worse, the next occupant doing something dangerously moronic *because he didn't understand your setup* -- the latter reason is why "weird setups that require knowledge to use safely" are prohibited.